# Deploying to production with Laravel 5.8 deletes my public uploads storage directory

Tags: php, laravel, envoyer.io

I am building my first site on Laravel 5.8 and for the most part things work as they should. I can create a new Post, upload a photo, hit save and the record persists to the database and I can see the Post data in my view, image and all.  I push my changes to my production server, create a new Post, image, etc... and things seem to work great. Until, I push another change from my local environment, then I realized my public/uploads directory is wiped out and any images uploaded to a Post has a broken image link.

**My Setup**

Laravel 5.8 (local and production), MySql 5.7 (local and production), Valet (local), Push to Bitbucket, [Envoyer](https://envoyer.io/) Pulls Changes and Auto deploys, Digital Ocean Droplet set via [Forge](https://forge.laravel.com)

**filesystems.php**

```
...
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path(),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
...
```

**PostController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $rules = [
        'title' => ['required', 'min:3'],
        'body' => ['required', 'min:5'],
        'photo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:4096M'
    ];
    $request->validate($rules);
    $user_id = Auth::id();
    $post = new Post();
    $post->user_id = $user_id;
    $post->is_featured = $request->input('is_featured', false);
    $post->is_place = $request->input('is_place', false);
    $post->title = request('title');
    $post->body = request('body');
    $post->place_name = request('place_name');
    $post->place_address = request('place_address');
    $post->place_city = request('place_city');
    $post->place_state = request('place_state');
    $post->place_zip = request('place_zip');
    $post->place_phone = request('place_phone');
    $post->place_email = request('place_email');
    $post->place_website = request('place_website');

    if ($request->has('photo')) {
        // Get image file
        $image = $request->file('photo');
        // Make a image name based on user name and current timestamp
        $name = Str::slug($request->input('name')).time();
        // Define folder path
        $folder = '/uploads/posts/' . $user_id . '/';
        // Make a file path where image will be stored [ folder path + file name + file extension]
        $filePath = $folder . $name. '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // Upload image
        $this->uploadOne($image, $folder, 'public', $name);
        // Set user profile image path in database to filePath
        $post->photo = $filePath;
    }

    $post->save();

    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('backend.auth.post.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This folder is probably **NOT VERSIONED**.

Add an empty `.gitkeep` file inside the folder (public/uploads), commit, push and redo the deploy.

Git doesn't keep empty folders.